# How to get main thread callstack on other thread in swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, callstack

The `Thread.callStackSymbols` can only get the current thread callstack, and I cant jump to main thread by GCD like this：

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let result = Thread.callStackSymbols
}
```

so, how to get main thread callstack on other thread

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: @NikhilManapure I want to get the call stack for the main thread in another thread,if I use DispatchQueue to the main thread, the callstack is not what I wanted.so, I want to know how to get the call stack for the main thread in another thread,just like what `PLCrashReporter`  did.